# Programmatically change state of a UISwitch bugs

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiswitch

I'm trying to dynamically change a UISwitch with the method `[self.mySwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];`

The state change as well in the code so that the mecanisme is working fine but in the view the state has not change. So I get a UISwitch shown as OFF and working as it was as ON.

When I tap on it, the switch became ON. So I have to tap it twice to launch the inCaseOff part of code.

I hope this is clear enough.

[EDIT]

This is the code you have asked

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [self manageTheSwitch];
}

- (void) manageTheSwitch{
    self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
    if(randomObject != nil){
        [self.mySwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self.mySwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: try to check if you update switch state on main thread. anyway you provide too little info to help you, post more code may be?

Comment: Did you add this switch to your view in IB or in code?

Comment: I realise what was my mistake. I shouldn't realloc mySwitch, this temporally broke the link betwen the controller and mySwitch. Remove this "self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];" solved my issue. Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're programmatically setting a different UISwitch to the one shown in your view. You shouldn't have to do `[[UISwitch alloc]init]` at all, instead you should retrieve it through an `IBOutlet` property in your controller (wired up to your view in IB).

Assuming you did wire up mySwitch, then all you need to do is remove this line:

```
self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that you're instantiating a new button in your manageTheSwitch method rather than accessing the one you created in the storyboard. Just eliminate that alloc init.

Answer (score 0):

try using the "selected" property UISwitch inherits from UIControl:
 `self.mySwitch.selected = YES;`